# How can I save an array values associated key to another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array full of lines from a text file. I'm using **preg_match** to find the lines in this array that contain a certain string.

Each time I find a match I want to push the key value for that line to another array so I end up with an array full of keys where the matches occur. I then want to iterate through this new array and perform an action for each match.

*How can I push **just the keys** to a new array?*

Comment: Side notice: why do you want to iterate through two loops, if you could perform the tasks in one loop.

Comment: So what do you want exactly? These could do the job: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this may help you:

```
$secondArray    = array();
foreach( $firstArray as $key=>$each ){
    if( your_condition_here ){
        $secondArray[]  = $key;    
    }

}
print_r( $secondArray );die;
```

Answer (score 1):

The array_keys() function is what you are looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

This answers 'How can I push just the keys to a new array?'

But I think Nil'z has gone in the right direction putting the preg_match() in the loop.

You might also want to look at the function array_walk() to process each element in an array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

So what about this code

```
$matching_keys = array();
array_walk($filelines, function($line, $key) {
    if(preg_match(...))
        $matching_keys[] = $key
});
array_walk($matching_keys, function($matching_key) {
    //do your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$new_arr = array_keys($array);
```